# replace 2 selected row values based on others

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df that looks like this:

```
Id     Class               Label
0      APPS                Item
1      MODEL               Item
2      PRICE               Money
```

I want to check all `Class`entries where the Label is `Item`. Among these classes, I want to replace all occurrences of `APPS` with another string `OTHERS`and want to replace the `Label` of such rows to another string eg `SOFTWARE`
How can I achieve this? I was trying something like this:

```
def changeLabelClass(label):
    if (label == "")
    
mask = modifiedDf['Label'] == "Item"
modifiedDf.loc[mask, 'Class'] = [changeLabelClass(x) for x in modifiedDf.loc[mask, 'Class']]
```

Outcome:

```
Id     Class               Label
0      OTHERS              SOFTWARE
1      MODEL               Item
2      PRICE               Money
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with chain 2 conditions by `&` for bitwise `AND` - here is assign list with 2 values because selected 2 columns `['Class', 'Label']`:

```
mask1 = df['Label'] == "Item"
mask2 = df['Class'] == "APPS"

df.loc[mask1 & mask2, ['Class', 'Label']] = ['OTHERS','SOFTWARE']
print (df)
   Id   Class     Label
0   0  OTHERS  SOFTWARE
1   1   MODEL      Item
2   2   PRICE     Money
```

Comment: After this I try to print the df or check the value counts, the values don't seem to be replaced

Comment: @a125 - Hmmm, reason should be no match one or another mask, is possible test it ? `df['m1'] = mask1` and `df['m2'] = mask2` and `print (df)`